# Can't Install R for the first time

Tags: r, windows

I am trying to install R and Rstudio from [CRAN](https://cran.rstudio.com/) but when I click it's not working, it's not doing anything whereas download should've been   started. I tried using chrome incognito mode to download but facing the same problem. Any solutions?

tried using incognito mode to encounter if chrome stopping the download permission

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 11

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. To be clear, is this the URL that you used? https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/base/R-4.3.1-win.exe The link should end in .exe for Windows 11.

Comment: Also, I had another question... Is it the same for installing RStudio too? because [link] https://download1.rstudio.org/electron/windows/RStudio-2023.06.1-524.exe is not doing anything also.


nvm got the problem, for some reason clicking the link from website is causing a problem, but when i copy the link and paste search it directly at browser it worked

nvm